# Error in Yoeman with generator-fountain-webapp

Tags: node.js, gulp, yeoman-generator, yo

I'm new to Yoeman and NodeJS. I was trying to follow the tutorial at http://yeoman.io/codelab/scaffold-app.html

I got an unexpected error in Step 3, after running `yo` following the options in Step 3, the error comes out:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /Users/shaunrong/anaconda3/envs/NodeJS/bin/git checkout 4ed9a4a3275559c73a396eff7e1fde3824951ebb
npm ERR! error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
npm ERR!    docs/why-use-pump/pipe-error.png
npm ERR!    docs/why-use-pump/pump-error.png
npm ERR! Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
npm ERR! Aborting
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shaunrong/.npm/_logs/2018-01-01T06_05_39_887Z-debug.log
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/shaunrong/Documents/PhD_Course/NodeJS/yo/.git/
```

This seems to be gulp related but I can't figure out how to resolve it. I am using NodeJS and npm within a conda virtual environment.

yo version is 2.0.0
npm version is 5.4.2
node version is v8.8.1

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: it seems to be those two files have been changed. Do a `git reset --hard`

Comment: It didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it was an upstream issue in gulp, we had the same troubles. Should be fixed now by this commit: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/commit/a010db615fae4fbf8ecfdaff5530a4d84107d984

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. look for this error if you have any deprecated. 
I found this one: `deprecated bower@1.8.2: ...psst! Your project can stop working at any moment because its dependencies can change. Prevent this by migrating to Yarn: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/`

and I think that is the problem.
good luck.